# Delete duplicate records except one with join three table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario for delete duplicate records from table and i am not getting the idea how to do this because of large data and relationship with three tables.

candidates_table is candidate table which contains duplicate records .
and fields are

```
candidate Table : 

candidate_id |f_name |l_name| skills

 1             Ab       c        php,MySQL 
 2             Ab       c        php,MySQL,java script
 3             cd       g        Java,hibernate,spring 
 4             cd       g        Java,hibernate 
 5             ef       h        XML,Web service
 6             ef       h        XML,Web service,json

Attachment Table:

attachment_id |candidate_id 

 1             2        
 2             4     
 3             8      
 4             9     
 5             10     

Canidate_job_order Table:

joborder_id |candidate_id 

 1             2        
 2             4     
 3             8      
 4             9     
 5             10
```

attachments_table is a table if any candidate  has attachment then candidate_id goes here.

candidate_joborder_table is contains if the candidate_id if he is submitted against any Job Order.

I have to delete that duplicate candidate from candidate table who has no attachment and is not submitted against any job order.Also i have to put 1 if everything matching same. I want to delete all records from candidate table except canidate_id 2,4,6 Any help .

Comment: This question is unclear! Please provide more details, some sample data and more info about the last request.

Comment: 1. See normalization

Answer (score 0):

Delete all candidates that don't have Attachment and didn't submit job order.

```
DELETE * FROM candidate WHERE candidate_id NOT IN (
     SELECT C.candidate_id FROM candidate C
     INNER JOIN Attachment A ON A.attachment_id = C.candidate_id
     INNER JOIN Canidate_job_order CJO ON CJO.candidate_id = C.C.candidate_id
)
```

*If some candidates have only attachment, this delete might not work if you have referenced tables with foreign keys!*

Comment: what about duplicate records

Comment: From your description, duplicate records in candidate table don't have referenced values in _Attachment_ and _Candidate_job_order_ and will be deleted.

Comment: there may be a record or not in reference table . we have to manage both conditions.

Comment: DELETE n1 FROM candidate n1, candidate n2 WHERE n1.candidate_id < n2.candidate_id 
AND n1.first_name = n2.first_name AND  n1.last_name=n2.last_name 
AND n1.key_skills=n2.key_skills AND
n1.city=n2.city AND n1.is_del is null

Comment: The above query is taking too much time to execute .can you tell me what  is the solution

Comment: OK, try this solution:

Comment: --Take all Candidates that have duplicate records into Temp table


`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS duplicateIDs AS 
(SELECT candidate_id FROM candidate GROUP BY candidate_id HAVING COUNT(candidate_id) > 1)`

Comment: --Take all Candidates that are marked as "duplicate". But, take only candidates that don't have Attachments and Orders

`SELECT C.* FROM candidate C 
JOIN duplicateIDs T ON C.candidate_id = T.candidate_id
LEFT JOIN Attachment A ON A.attachment_id = C.candidate_id
LEFT JOIN Canidate_job_order CJO ON CJO.candidate_id = C.candidate_id
WHERE A.attachment_id IS NULL AND CJO.candidate_id IS NULL`

Comment: If this SELECT returns data that has to be deleted, then just perform DELETE command with the same joins

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
delete from candidate c where candidate_id not in (select max(candidate_id) 

from candidate 
group by f_name ,l_name, skills) 
and not exists (select 1 from Attachment A where A.attachment_id = C.candidate_id) 
and not exists (select 1 from Canidate_job_order CJO where CJO.candidate_id = C.C.candidate_id) and not in ( 2,4,6);
```

Comment: we don't know the ids not in ( 2,4,6) . what about duplicate records

Comment: ids not in ( 2,4,6) means"I want to delete all records from candidate table except canidate_id 2,4,6"

Comment: Updated the answer to delete duplicate. Finds distinct rows by select max. Delete the rest.

Comment: DELETE n1 FROM candidate n1, candidate n2 WHERE n1.candidate_id < n2.candidate_id AND n1.first_name = n2.first_name AND n1.last_name=n2.last_name AND n1.key_skills=n2.key_skills AND n1.city=n2.city AND n1.is_del is null

Comment: query is taking too much time to execute. is there any solution